# How can I get my userinput to access my ArrayList when I pass it to a method

Tags: java

Here's the code I have so far.  This is the error I get for line 58

> incompatible types   required: ArrayList   found:
>   VendProduct

(Alt-Enter shows hints)

//A vending machine to dispense multiple products

```
package newvendingmachine;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

//Tony Moore 

public class NewVendingMachine{
    //Set class data
    static String[] product = {"Chips", "M&Ms", "Peanuts", "Popcorn", "Snickers"};
    static Float[] cost = {.50f, .75f, .75f, .75f, .90f};
    static Integer[] inventory = {20, 20, 20, 20, 20};

    /** 
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<VendProduct> vp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int idx=0; idx<product.length; idx++) {
            vp.add(new VendProduct());
        }

        //Accept user input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
        int userInput;

        while (true) {
            // Display menu graphics

            System.out.println(" Options: Press your selection then press enter ");
            System.out.println(" 1. "+product[0]+" ");
            System.out.println(" 2. "+product[1]+" ");
            System.out.println(" 3. "+product[2]+" ");
            System.out.println(" 4. "+product[3]+" ");
            System.out.println(" 5. "+product[4]+" ");
            System.out.println(" 6. Quit ");


            userInput = input.nextInt(); 

            if (userInput <1 || userInput >6) {
                System.out.println("Please make a vaild selection");    
            }

            if (userInput >=1 || userInput <=6) {
                vp = (VendProduct)vp.get(userInput-1);
                vp.buyProduct();         
            }

            if (userInput == 6) {
                System.out.println("Thanks, and come back soon");
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: which is line 58? I don't want to count ;)

Comment: Line 58 is vp = (VendProduct)vp.get(userInput -1);

Answer (score 0):

`vp = (VendProduct)vp.get(userInput-1);`

`vp` is an ArrayList of VendProduct, but you're trying to set it to just one VendProduct...

You should create a variable of the type `VendProduct` and use that, like this:

```
 VendProduct product = vp.get(userInput-1);
 product.buyProduct();
```

You could also do `vp.get(userInput-1).buyProduct();` directly in one line. That's up to you. Using two lines usually makes the code a bit cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I gave your suggestion a try but I recieved the followinng error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at newvendingmachine2.NewVendingMachine2.main(NewVendingMachine2.java:56) buyProduct is an another class called VendFunctions and is public void buyProduct(){
         
         System.out.println(product);
    }

Comment: @Tony Well, I can't help you solve that without seeing more of your code. Especially the `VendFunctions` and `VendProduct` classes.

Comment: I'm still learning the interface here.  I'll be happy to provide the code.  I had to turn the assignment in already, but I still want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: @Tony then please edit your original question and add the remaining code.